# For which prime numbers $p$ does the congruence $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ have solutions?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences, quadratic-residues

For which prime numbers p does the congruence $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ have solutions?

We've recently learnt about quadratic reciprocity in class, however I am not sure how to tackle this problem. I have tried starting with the $b^2-4ac$ (discriminant) but that hasn't really helped.

Comment: $p=3$, $p=7$ for instance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  I am glad you found the help you needed on this question.  There is information about writing mathematics on this site here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.  Also, the quantity $b^2 - 4ac$ is called the discriminant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $4(x^2 +x+1) = (2x+1)^2 + 3$. Therefore, if it has a solution modulo $p$, $-3$ must be a quadratic residue. Use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: So following from that I should find p for which (-3/p)=1?

Comment: Yes. Remember that $(-3|p) = (-1|p)(3|p)$. Then, you either need that both -1 and 3 are quadratic residues or both are quadratic non-residues. $(-1|p) \equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \pmod{p}$, and for 3 use quadratic reciprocity

Comment: Okay, so I get (-3/p)=(-1)^(p-1)(p/3) which is dependent on pmod3 then it works for p=1 and p=2, does this mean it holds for all p equivalent to 1 or 2 mod 3? Also what about p=3?

Comment: For $p=3$ you must handle it separately. You can see that $x=1$ is a solution. And yes, if $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$ then $(a|p)=(b|p)$.
Also, be careful, $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$.

Comment: So if it holds for p=3, does this imply it holds for all p as we already have it working for p=1 or 2 mod 3?

Comment: It doesn't work for $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ because, as you've seen $(-3|p) = (p|3)$ and $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$.

Comment: I thought (-3|p)=(-1)^(p-1) (p|3) so 2 would work?

Comment: You can check that $p=2$ doesn't work by hand, and then, if $p$ is a prime, it must be odd. So $p-1$ is even and then $(-1)^{p-1}=1$. That is, $(-3|p) = (p|3)$.

Comment: Ah I see, and then you have it holds for p as long as p is equivalent to 1 or 3 mod3?

Comment: Yep, that's it :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than reciprocity: $\,x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \,\overset{\large {\cdot\, (x-1)}}\Rightarrow\,x^3\equiv 1,\ $ so by [basic results on cyclic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30185/242) $\ldots$