# Number of subgroups of the Cartesian product $C_9 \times C_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $C_9$ denote the the cyclic group of order $9$. What is the number of subgroups of the Cartesian product $C_9 \times C_9$ that are isomorphic to $C_9$. (NBHM 2023).

The answer is 12. But I can't get that.... I found 10 subgroups (which are generated by the elements of the group $C_9 \times C_9$) that are isomorphic to $C_9$. I can't get the exact approch.

Any hint or solution is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: how many elements of order 9 in this group? how many of them inside a given cyclic subgroup of order 9?

Answer (score 3):

There are $9\times9-1=80$ non-trivial elements, in which $9-1=8$ of them have order $3$, and $80-8=72$ of them have order $9$.

Each order $9$ element generates a copy of $C_9$, $C_9$ contains one proper subgroup $C_3$, therefore in each copy of $C_9$ there are $9-3=6$ generators

Counting the number of generators you get $72/6=12$ such subgroups, they are generated by
(1,0),(1,3),(1,6)
(0,1),(3,1),(6,1)
(1,1),(1,4),(1,7)
(1,2),(1,5),(1,8)

Comment: $(0,3)$ and $(0,6)$ have order $3$

Comment: right, they should be (3,1), (6,1), I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

To find the number of cyclic subgroup of order $9$, first find the number of elements of order $9$.

Now [$|(a,b)| = lcm(|a|,|b|)$ ,for $(a,b) \in C_9×C_9$.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#:%7E:text=This%20follows%20from%20the%20formula,orders%20of%20g%20and%20h%20.)

So order $9$ elements are those where

$1.\; |a|=9 ,|b|=1$

$2.\; |a|=1 ,|b|=9$

$3.\; |a|=3 , |b|=9 $

$4.\; |a|= 9, |b|=3 $

$5.\; |a|=9 , |b|=9 $

Now find number of these elements using the fact that there are [$\;\phi(k)$ ($\phi$ is Euler phi function) elements of order $k$ in a cyclic group,where $k$ divides order of the group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30208/934187)

You will get $72$ elements of order $9$.So number of cyclic subgroup of order $9 = \frac{72}{\phi(9)}$ =$12$